# Line length in fancyvrb

Tags: line-breaking, verbatim, line-numbering

What I'm doing: Typsetting source code using [pygments](http://pygments.org/).

What is happening: the code typsets fine, but because pygments puts the code into a Verbatim environment, some of the lines are far too long.

What I want to have happen: I want the lines to break at the edge of the column without adding extra lines in the line numbering.

What I've tried: reading the fancyvrb documentation, using BVerbatim and LVerbatim.

Is there a way to either automatically break the lines or insert line breaks without adding line numbers?

Comment: Another option would be to use shorter lines in the first place.

Comment: I could do that. But then I'd have to rewrite all of my code to fit into a specific tech document style. That sounds like a lot more work than just using a different package.

Comment: Well, whether it's a good choice or not depends on what the goals of the document and code are, obviously, as well as on how much work it would be to do... like, if you're documenting some messy real-world application, that's different from if writing a "functional pearls" paper.

Comment: That's true. I've typeset code using pygments in the past, and had great luck with it. In this specific case, I needed line wrap, which is why I asked about line wrap. Listings is working beautifully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to this question--for me--turned out to be: use the **listings** package instead, it typsets Ruby code and provides line wrap.

Comment: So, you don't use verbatim?