# Verbatim environment and line-breaking

Tags: line-breaking, verbatim

I've been wondering about how to display simple codes. I used `verbatim` and then found the `fancyvrb` package which added a lot of nice little features, but then I inserted some code with a long line and it did not break.

I looked around and found that this was apparently a problem with this package, and thus looked for alternative ways to display code, and found `listings` (I found that it displayed the code strangely, I like the typewriter look of verbatim) and `minted` coupled with the `Pygments` Python tool (but I never got it to work with winshell). While looking at the 'listings' documentation I saw the 'fancyvrb' listed as an alternative, and in the description it said

> The package provides frames, line
>   numbers on the left or on the right,
>   automatic line breaking (difficult)...

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5125/line-length-in-fancyvrb) does not get an answer to the question of how to break lines using the `fancyvrb` package. I googled around and found this [solution](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2009-04/msg00306.html) which provides a way to have automatic line-breaking in the `verbatim` environment, but this solution does not work with the `fancyvrb` package.

So the question is: The `listings` documentation hints at a way to have automated line-breaking in the `fancyvrb` package, does anyone know how?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't see any major problems with the [listings](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) package. See example below for a very basic structure.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{%
  language=[LaTeX]TeX,
  backgroundcolor=\color{gray!25},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  breaklines=true,
  columns=fullflexible
}

\begin{document}
  \lstinputlisting{minimal.cls}
\end{document}
```

The package manual has the details.