# Verbatim environment that can break long lines?

Tags: line-breaking, verbatim

I want to generate a PDF of user-submitted text using LaTeX. To handle crazy user input, I first thought about using the `verbatim` package, but of course it doesn't break up too long lines. Is there some package that works similar to `verbatim` (i.e., accept any input) but formats the text nicely?

Comment: I didn't find a way to use the verbatim package - instead I tried to cover all special cases by unrolling all LaTeX commands and all "special" characters.

Answer (score 55):

The `listings` package provides you with a verbatim environment which can break lines:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines]
  Long user text
\end{lstlisting}
```

If the user text is in an external file you can also use:

```
\lstinputlisting[breaklines]{filename}
```

Comment: See also the answer at <http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11973/verbatim-environment-and-line-breaking> for an example of adjusting the formatting of the `lstlisting` environment.

Comment: This works better for me that the second option spverbatim, which breaks the long text only after the page span and hence some text is not seen...

Comment: will not work properly with UTF-8 chars out of the box

Comment: I'm writing in italian and UTF-8 issues of this package are really difficult to manage

Answer (score 24):

```
\usepackage{spverbatim}
...

\begin{spverbatim}
This is a very long line.1

\end{spverbatim}
```

The `spverbatim` package enables LaTEX to break lines at spaces within verbatim
text.

Comment: @MartinScharrer I am trying to create my own environments with this package. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309042/how-can-i-redefine-verbatim-to-wrap-lines-add-break-before-or-after-spaces

Answer (score 18):

The `fancyvrb` package in combination with the [`fvextra` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fvextra) allows you to use linebreaks in the `Verbatim` environment by specifying the `breaklines=true` option:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{fvextra}

\begin{document}
The following is printed verbatim, but with line breaks:
\begin{Verbatim}[breaklines=true]
This is a very long line that will need to be broken into pieces otherwise it will run into and out of the margins
\end{Verbatim}
Alternatively, line breaks can be put anywhere, not just at white space:
\begin{Verbatim}[breaklines=true, breakanywhere=true]
Thisisaverylonglinethatwillneedtobebrokenintopiecesotherwiseitwillrunintoandoutofthemargins
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the fvextra example]

Comment: As mentioned in the documentation, it's also possible to set this option globally with `\fvset{breaklines=true}`

Comment: Not working in overleaf: `fvextra.sty not found.' or 'Missing number, treated as zero.' if trying to skip fvextra

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what you exactly need, this might be sufficient: we reset all special characters to catcode other, in particular \, { and } lose their meaning. This will make it pretty hard to inject LaTeX code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\saferead[1]{%
  \bgroup
  \let\do\@makeother
  \dospecials\catcode`\ 10
  \input{#1}%
  \egroup 
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
And to show it, we input ourselves: \saferead{test.tex}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\def\@xobeysp{ }` in the preamble of your document to make all spaces regular (breaking) spaces. This will not hyphenate or break ultra-long words, though.

To format the text nicely, you can use the `Verbatim` environment, in the `fancyvrb` package:

```
\begin{Verbatim}[formatcom=\sffamily]
  Hello world hello world hello world
  Test
\end{Verbatim}
```

<sup><sub>Will print the text in a Sans-seriF font family.</sub></sup>

Though (I'm sorry!) the `\def\@xobeysp{ }` won't work with the `Verbatim` environment... So you must choose between the two.