# How to prevent contents of verbatim text from running off the page?

Tags: line-breaking, verbatim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Verbatim environment that can break too long lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14342/verbatim-environment-that-can-break-too-long-lines)

How to prevent contents of verbatim text from running off the page?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

Need to add {\tt contrib}
\begin{verbatim}
peter@debpet:~$ gksudo mousepad /etc/apt/sources.list



#You commented out deb-src in the process too as it is not needed if you just apt-get and use Synaptic; it's only for expert users who want to inspect src and compile from scratch

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux testing _Wheezy_ - Official Snapshot i386 NETINST Binary-1 20110904-21:43]/ wheezy main

deb http://mirror.optus.net/debian/ wheezy main {\bf contrib} non-free
#deb-src http://mirror.optus.net/debian/ wheezy main



deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
#deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main

\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A couple of options have been suggested at [Verbatim environment that can break too long lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14342/verbatim-environment-that-can-break-too-long-lines).