# ttfamily usage (newline failing)

Tags: line-breaking, typewriter

I'm unable to insert a new line while using `\ttfamily`.
Is there any reason why `\ttfamily` prevents to do that?

My problem (here's the code):

```
Let's consider an e-commerce web application whose address is:
\begin{ttfamily} https://website-test.com/scripts/GetEBook.aspx?file=ebook7.pdf \end{ttfamily}
```

I repeatedly tried to insert the `\newline` command after the word `is` in order to get the output:

```
Let's consider an e-commerce web application whose address is:

https://website-test.com/scripts/GetEBook.aspx?file=ebook7.pdf
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work...I get no new line.

Also, how do I insert spaces in order to move the text forward?

For example:

```
\begin{ttfamily} \verb https://website-test.com/scripts/GetEBook.aspx?file= \end{ttfamily}
\begin{ttfamily} \verb ..\..\windows\repair\sam \end{ttfamily}
```

I'd like the output to be:

```
https://website-test.com/scripts/GetEBook.aspx?file=
                            ..\..\windows\repair\sam
```

If `\ttfamily` doesn't allow to do what I need, is there any other way to solve the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Verbatim environment that can break too long lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14342/verbatim-environment-that-can-break-too-long-lines)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
\noindent Let's consider an e-commerce web application whose address is:
\vspace{.5cm}
\par\noindent
\begin{ttfamily}%
https://website-test.com/scripts/GetEBook.aspx?file=ebook7.pdf
\end{ttfamily}
\par\noindent
\begin{ttfamily}%
https://website-test.com/scripts/GetEBook.aspx?file=
\end{ttfamily}
\par\noindent
\begin{ttfamily}%
\hspace{5.2cm}\verb|..\..\windows\repair\sam|
\end{ttfamily}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, if you are trying to write a url address, it is better to use `url` package. Here the advantage is, if used with `hyperref`, you can make the url click-able.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
\noindent Let's consider an e-commerce web application whose address
is:\\[.5cm]
\url{https://website-test.com/scripts/GetEBook.aspx?file=ebook7.pdf}
\par\noindent
\url{https://website-test.com/scripts/GetEBook.aspx?file=}\\
\hspace*{5.2cm}\verb|..\..\windows\repair\sam|
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks very much..but if I'm not wrong after the phrase "whose address is:" there's no space..While the solution to the other problem (horizontal space) works perfectly..

Comment: @ Harish Kumar I mean I should get a new line..as I stated ..I used the command \\ as you did now..thanks

Comment: @g9999 We say thanks here in TeX.SX by upvoting and accepting the most useful answer (by clicking the green check mark below the votecount) so that the question may be considered as answered. This is the tradition followed here. You may wait for some time before accepting the answers, though.