# Line breaks in listings

Tags: listings, line-breaking

Is there a way like *wrap the line after at most 60 letters* but it should **not break inside some commands** like `listings` does?

Example:

```
    \documentclass[a5paper]{article}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{listings}
    \usepackage{xcolor}

    \lstset{%
      language=[LaTeX]TeX,
      backgroundcolor=\color{gray!25},
      basicstyle=\ttfamily,
      breaklines=true,
      columns=fullflexible
    }

    \begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}
    The roadrunner is the fastest running bird \remark{Check this again with a zoologist!}.
    \end{lstlisting}
    \end{document}
```

Output:

```
    The roadrunner is the fastest running bird         remark{Check this again with a zoologist!}.
```

That should not happen! In my eyes this problem is not discussed in [`verbatim` environment that can break too long lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14342/verbatim-environment-that-can-break-too-long-lines).

Comment: Would `breakatwhitespace=true` be good enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Torbjørn T., my question is answered:

One simply has to say:

```
\lstset{%
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
}
```