# Line breaks in listings with long lines

Tags: listings, line-breaking

This is a follow-up question to [Line breaks in listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97728/line-breaks-in-listings/99448)

My MWE with a very long line demonstrate the problem:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinelanguage{text}{}
\lstnewenvironment{mylang}{\lstset{language=text,breaklines=true,breakatwhitespace=false,extendedchars=true,basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,}}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{mylang}
demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo

demodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemo 
\end{mylang}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`listings` add break points only after chars of type "other". You tell it to add e.g. `o` to the list, but this will break the parsing of keywords:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
\lstset{keywords=demo,keywordstyle=\color{red},breaklines}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
    demo
    demodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemo
\end{lstlisting}


\begin{lstlisting}[alsoother=o]
    demo
    demodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemodemo
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how to manage adding `other` and parsing of keywords at the same time?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: what about the `otherkeywords` option? (see `listings` [documentation](ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf))