# Lstlisting running off screen

Tags: listings, margins

The text in my `lstlisting` is running out of screen on the right. I googled, but only found problems with the code box's position on the left side, and white lines. My problem is that it does not know when to move text to the next line. All below shows as a single line, where most is outside the frame on the right. Any help is much appreciated. I compile using `pdflatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings} % Required for insertion of code
\begin{document}
\appendix
\section{Appendix}
\begin{lstlisting}
This random text is going of screen to the right. This random text is going of screen to the right. This random text is going of screen to the right. This random text is going of screen to the right. This random text is going of screen to the right. This random text is going of screen to the right. 
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `breaklines=true`

Comment: [Line breaks in listings](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97795)

Comment: A concise introduction to **listings** package can be found [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings)