# Using Sagetex on cloud.sagemath.com, is it possible to make Sageblock code wrap automatically?

Tags: line-breaking, verbatim, sagetex

Creating a LaTeX document on the Sage Math Cloud. Whenever I use a `sageblock`, I end up with endless typesetting warnings because the notes and code inside the `sageblock` does not automatically wrap when a line gets too long. Is there a simple fix for this?

edit: I'm referring specifically to `overfull \hbox` warnings. For example, in trying to define the following plot, the `sageblock` code that displays in the finished pdf will not automatically wrap onto the next line.

```
\begin{sageblock}
realtopcircleplot=plot(realtopcircle,downbaseterminus-1,circleEnd-1)
\end{sageblock}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you mean `overfull hbox` warnings? Can you add a complete, minimal example of code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: To be precise, those are warnings, not errors. As far as I can see, `sagetex` uses a `verbatim` environment for `sageblock`, and loads the `verbatim` package. I'm afraid I have no idea whether it's possible to redefine that environment to allow linebreaking though. (Oh, and by 'complete' I meant starting with `\documentclass`, including necessary packages (notably `sagetex`), ending with `\end{document}`. It makes it easier for those trying to help, as they won't have to set up a complete document, and they don't have to make any guesses or assumptions about your code.)

Comment: If no one posts a solution, you could ask the `sagetex` developers if it is possible to add this feature. The main developer is Dan Drake (http://mathsci.kaist.ac.kr/~drake/)

Answer (score 1):

Right now there's no way to do this. SageTeX uses the `verbatim` environment to both typeset the Sage code and to write out that code to the `.sagetex.sage` file. It seems like the [listings package can do the typesetting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14342/verbatim-environment-that-can-break-too-long-lines), but I don't know if `listings` can write out its input to a file.