# Escape a string printed from Lua using ConTeXt

Tags: luatex, context-mkiv, lua

This seems to have come up a couple times, but I cannot glean an answer to the generic question of how one might protect an arbitrary string in Lua to ensure its characters are printed.

In other words, given some code in a `.lua` file:

```
local i_can_be_anything = '&\\%*_'
context(i_can_be_anything)
```

This balks for any number of reasons, because the characters have special meaning in TeX when ConTeXt pushes them out to the TeX compiler.

The most apparent option to me would be to convert the string in Lua so that it contains the proper escaping or substitutions that can be passed to TeX to achieve the desired outcome, which would be in this case along the lines of:

```
\&\textbackslash{}\%\&\_
```

I believe the full list of replacements one would be looking for would be along the lines of (and this is from some Python I wrote):

```
tex_replacements = [
    (u'{', ur'\{'),
    (u'}', ur'\}'),
    (u'[', ur'{[}'),
    (u']', ur'{]}'),
    (u'\\', ur'\textbackslash{}'),
    (u'$', ur'\$'),
    (u'%', ur'\%'),
    (u'&', ur'\&'),
    (u'#', ur'\#'),
    (u'_', ur'\_'),
    (u'~', ur'\textasciitilde{}'),
    (u'^', ur'\textasciicircum{}'),
]

tex_mapping =  {ord(char):rep for char, rep in tex_replacements}
def escape(s):
    return unicode(s).translate(tex_mapping)
```

Is there no function in Lua or LuaTeX to achieve this set of substitutions (or otherwise) so that an arbitrary string could be printed?

A straightforward iteration over the characters with a substitution along the lines of the `tex_replacements` above could do the trick, but I would expect that someone had already written a solution to this problem.

---

#### EDIT

It is worth noting that @phg posed a plausible solution of changing the catcodes to vrbcatcode (i.e. `\verbatim`, or `context.sprint(catcodes.numbers.vrbcatcodes, i_can_be_anything)`). This does perform the escaping desired, however it seems to [have serious issues with line breaking](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14342) that make it essentially unusable.

Comment: The solution you are looking for is switching the catcode table. ``vrbcatcodes`` should suffice for most literal printing, but if you like you can skim the list for a more appropriate one: http://git.contextgarden.net/context/context/blob/master/tex/context/base/catc-def.mkiv (Btw. there is no such thing as a “TeX compiler”.)

Comment: Thanks @phg. I am afraid it is not apparent from the link how one employs said catcodes. Incidentally, and aside, if there is no such thing as a TeX compiler, what is the mechanism by which the TeX source is converted to machine instructions?

Comment: You can use ``\pushcatcodetable \setcatcodetable \somecatcodetable`` to set the table and ``\popcatcodetable`` to drop it again (that’s ``context.pushcatcodetable() context.setcatcodetable(catcodes.numbers.vrbcatcodes)`` / ``context.popcatcodetable()`` at the Lua end, or use ``context.sprint(n, ...)`` with the catcode table as the first argument). As for the terminology: TeX is *interpreted* by a TeX engine.

Comment: (Untested) `context(catcodes.numbers.vrbcatcodes, i_can_be_anything)` should also work.

Comment: @Aditya [Are you sure?](http://git.contextgarden.net/context/context/blob/master/tex/context/base/cldf-ini.lua#L839) It calls ``tex.sprint()`` explicitly with the currently active catcode table. There is ``context.verbatim()``, though, which sets the ``vrbcatcodes`` table.

Comment: It looks like the proper catcode might be `\notcatcodes` from [catc-def.mkiv](http://math.sut.ac.th/lab/software/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/catc-def.mkiv)

Comment: @phg: Clearly, I was mistaken. See my answer for a "proper" solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is based on an email from Hans Hagen. One way to achieve the desired output is using *formatters*. For example:

```
\starttext
\startluacode
  local text='&\%*_'
  context("%!tex!", text)
\stopluacode
\stoptext
```

The `%!tex!` is plug to the formatters and `tex` is one of the pre-defined formatters. Other pre-defined formatters are `lua` and `xml` (which escape strings for Lua and XML, respectively).

The above code is equivalent to

```
context(string.formatters["%!tex!"](text))
```

which is equivalent to the rather low-level

```
context(lpeg.match(lpeg.patterns.texescape,text))
```

The corresponding lpeg patterns for `lua` and `xml` formatters are `lpeg.patterns.luaescape` and `lpeg.patterns.xmlescape`. These are defined in `util-str.lua` as:

```
patterns.xmlescape = Cs((P("<")/"&lt;" + P(">")/"&gt;" + P("&")/"&amp;" + P('"')/"&quot;" + P(1))^0)
patterns.texescape = Cs((C(S("#$%\\{}"))/"\\%1" + P(1))^0)
patterns.luaescape = Cs(((1-S('"\n'))^1 + P('"')/'\\"' + P('\n')/'\\n"')^0) -- maybe also \0
patterns.luaquoted = Cs(Cc('"') * ((1-S('"\n'))^1 + P('"')/'\\"' + P('\n')/'\\n"')^0 * Cc('"'))
```

The `luaquoted` pattern is not used in the core.

Comment: Thanks Aditya - why do you think one would prefer these over the discussed catcodes? other than Hans saying so, which ought to be compelling enough :-) —just curious.

Comment: One note, `context("%!tex!", text)` seems to handle `"\"`  in an unintuitive way. For example, the string `"\escape"` results in `"<LINEBREAK>escape"`. This may not be the desired behaviour. The catcodes solution does not have this particular caveat.

Comment: It converts `\ ` to `\\ `, which I guess is mapped to `\crlf`.

Answer (score 1):

I am summarizing the comments here, but the gist is:

@phg suggested that one can escape by using [catcodes](http://git.contextgarden.net/context/context/blob/master/tex/context/base/catc-def.mkiv). There is the `verbatim` catcode, but it has [issues with linebreaks](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Verbatim_with_line_breaks).

An alternative, albeit undocumented but seemingly preferable (i.e. escapes without wrapping issues), catcode is `\notcatcodes`.

One can employ this in Lua to escape any string with the following, for example:

```
context.sprint(catcodes.numbers.notcatcodes, str)
-- or --
context.pushcatcodetable()
context.setcatcodetable(catcodes.numbers.vrbcatcodes)
context(str)
context.popcatcodetable()
```