# Nicely typesetting verbatim text

Tags: pdftex, verbatim

I want an environment in which LaTeX typesets the text just like it otherwise would, but without accepting any commands whatsoever while within this environment. None of the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14342/verbatim-environment-that-can-break-too-long-lines) solves the problem. Neither does `fancyvrb`, nor the `verbatim` packages.

I need this functionality, as I'm composing a LaTeX document from several plain text sources, with text written by authors with no idea of TeX or LaTeX. So the environment should treat everything as normal text. It should break lines, hyphenate words and just do what LaTeX does to normal text.

Do anyone have an idea on how to solve this problem?

EDIT:

An example would be someone writing this, in the plain text input field:

[image: Plain text input]

That will result in the following PDF output:

[image]

All is still fine, but then someone comes up with the fine idea of writing "\textbf{}" somewhere in the text. It could really be anything, like "%" or "$" or "_", but I think you get the idea. The text input now looks like:

[image]

And the PDF output looks like:

[image]

But I want it to look like:

[image]

So, I'm looking for an environment like:

[image]

which still typesets the text like it would any other text, but ignores all special characters and commands. I really, really don't want to write a parser which does all of the magic if I can avoid it...

EDIT 2:

Using the method devised in the answer from David Carlisle:

[image]

results in this PDF:

[image]

So not quite there yet.

EDIT 3:

Mea culpa - We absolutely are there. I've forgotten to add the "\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}". I can't make it fail, so I'm happy. Thanks David!

Comment: Can you then not use `\input{foo}` and put the plain text inside foo.tex?  You can't really have it both ways. It is either Verbatim or not ;)

Comment: Can you provide an example of such a text and the expected output?

Comment: @Nasser why can you not have it both ways?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle because when I googled for a Latex package called `\usepackage{almost_verbatim}` I did not find any  :)

Comment: It makes the site very confusing if you edit the answer into the question. You only get `"` for `\ ` as you don't copy the code correctly, you need `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: Ah, yes. I've forgotten to \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}. Now it does seem to work beautifully. Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\setlength\textwidth{20em}


\begingroup
\makeatletter
\gdef\plaintext{\let\do\@makeother\dospecials\catcode32=10\relax\xplaintext}
\catcode`\!=0
!catcode`\\=12
!catcode`{=12
!catcode`}=12
!catcode`(=1
!catcode`)=2
!long!gdef!xplaintext#1\end{plaintext}(%
#1!end(plaintext))
!endgroup



\begin{document}


\begin{plaintext}

this % text has ^ & _ but seems to work alright, hyphenation 
or extremely longish words seems to work OK.

Blank lines do form a paragraph but \this is not an undefined
command and \includegraphics{this is not a picture}

\end{plaintext}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could this code be made into a package to make it easy to use for users? as in `\usepackage{plaintext}` and have it be part of `TexLive` distribution? This would be very useful. thanks.

Comment: @Nasser I think you'll find the licence is such that you may do that, yes:-)

Comment: Does this still work if I ask a question like this in the environment!?!?!???!?!?!? (Point being: can you still have exclamation marks in there?)

Comment: @SeanAllred you should have more faith:-)

Comment: The only place where this don't work is in a title, like : \chapter{A \begin{plaintext} \textbf{short} \end{plaintext} example}. But there's properly a good reason for that.

Comment: @colding that is same as `\verb` no command involving catcode changes works in the argument of another command, as the text has been tokenized with normal latex catcodes by the argument scanner of the outer command before the special command is started.

Comment: @colding for special cases like that just use `\chapter[something safe for toc]{A \detokenize{ \textbf{short}} example}` then there are more conditions:  you need to match braces and can't use %, and spaces after command names go  for example.

Comment: @David Ah, I see. I think I'll just yell at anyone putting anything but plaintext into the title input fields. Seems like the most practical solution :-)

Answer (score 6):

This approach uses `\detokenize`, but wraps it in a paragraph parser, which will format lines and indeed paragraphs in a verbatim-*like* manner.  EDITED to incorporate a trap for the `%` character, taking a nod from David's approach.  However, there is (at least) one area where it will break:  unmatched braces `{}`.

However, this limitation may or may not pose an insurmountable problem for you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand\verbpars{\bgroup\catcode`\%=12 \verbparsProper}
\newcommand\verbparsProper[1]{\verbparhelp#1\par\relax\relax\egroup}
\long\def\verbparhelp#1\par#2\relax{%
  \detokenize{#1}\ifx\relax#2\else\par\verbparhelp#2\relax\fi}
\begin{document}
\verbpars{%
this is a test $#@\\&!@~`_<>|\ this is a test $#@\\&!@~` this is a test $#@\\&!@~`
  this is a test $#@\\&!@~` this is a test $#@\\&!@~` this is a test $#@\\&!@~`

and now I have another test.} Regular \LaTeX{} continued in same par.

\verbpars{I have succeeded in making it work with an unquoted 
  percent sign % but it will still break with unmatched braces{}.  

But otherwise it may get you what you need.}

% This should not be seen
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: probably safest to just make % catcode 12 locally as in my answer, otherwise comments in included files will be tricky:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Fixed