# Formatting Code around Line Breaks

Tags: formatting, line-breaking, verbatim, code

I am typing up a sentence which contains code, and `\verb`'s ignorance of line breaks is annoying me. This code is very short, and it does not make sense to give it its own line, but I also do not think that it would be good to break it up over multiple lines like `texttt` would do. Is there a standard way to format code in a LaTeX document which plays nicely with the newlines in a paragraph? Here is an image of the effect to which I am referring:
[image]

Comment: Packages `fancyvrb`, `listings` perhaps?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14347/92620 ?

Comment: If you don't want to break it, and you don't want it hanging off the edge, they you probably want \sloppy of \raggedright, or at least \linebreak[3].

Comment: Can you squeeze an elephant in a suitcase?

Comment: @egreg My father's turn of phrase was a bit more colorful, questioning whether one could squeeze 2 pounds of, ahem, "manure" into a 1-pound sack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with the `listings` package using its `\lstinline` (`listings` equivalent of `\verb`) with the option `breaklines`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}
\begin{document}

This is my sentence which has some code a little bit later but
\lstinline[breaklines]+RIGHT HERE IN THE LINE+ which is overflowing and does
not seem to want to obey my margin constraints, so I am not entirely sure what
to do with it.

\end{document}
```

[image]