# linebreaks in lstlisting and verbatim environment

Tags: listings, line-breaking, paragraphs, verbatim

`longline*.txt` files contain some text and in some files the text is inserted in an environment as indicated in the filename.

The following script:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\input{longline.txt}

\input{longline_verbatim.txt}

\input{longline_lstlisting.txt}

\end{document}
```

reveals a different rendering of the text:

[image]

The actual text contains characters such as `_` and the `lstlisting` and `verbatim` environments are evaluated as a rescue.

The problem is that the paragraph is not broken down into lines in the `verbatim` and `lstlisting` environment.

How to solve the problem?

Comment: Have you seen [Verbatim environment that can break long lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14342/117534) Is the `\input` necessary in this code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example for the listings package can help you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]

    \lstset{
        linewidth=\linewidth,
        breaklines,
        breakatwhitespace=true,
        breakindent=0pt,
        basicstyle=\fontsize{9}{11}\usefont{T1}{cmr}{m}{n}\selectfont
    }
    \lstinputlisting{long.txt}
\end{document}
```

The file `long.txt` contains plain text divided into paragraphs:
[image]

And the result:
[image]