# Writing Bloc of Code in Latex (Curl)

Tags: verbatim, code

I am writing a bloc of code in Latex, my problem is that this code is not written well as it contains special chars . How can I deal with that .
NB: I have used verbatim like that

```
\begin{verbatim}
My bloc of code.......
\end{verbatim}
```

But if the text is too wide it does not return to line and also using \n does not solve the problem

Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably you are interested in the `listings` or the `minted` package.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14342/verbatim-environment-that-can-break-long-lines.

Comment: In fact I want to format programming language code

Comment: Then the `listings` package from the first comment can be useful. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings for an introduction, or the [package manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf).