# Is it possible to auto wrap in verbatim package?

Tags: equations, verbatim

Is it possible to auto-wrap in the verbatim package? Currently, my code doesn't work. It looks weird.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\documentclass[twocolumn]{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
  cypher1 = MATCH (c:Product)-[r1:requiredProcess]->(d:Process) where c.ProductName  = 'Product1' WITH COUNT(DISTINCT(d)) as number RETURN 'Process Number:'
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't think it's possible. Use some other package.

Comment: If you accept using other packages would be duplicate of  [Verbatim environment that can break long lines? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14342/verbatim-environment-that-can-break-long-lines/451397#451397)

Comment: why use verbatim here if you do not need to preserve white space? `\texttt{cypher1 = MATCH (c:Product)-[r1:requiredProcess]->(d:Process) where c.ProductName  = 'Product1' WITH COUNT(DISTINCT(d)) as number RETURN 'Process Number:'}` would seem more natural

Comment: which package should I use?

Comment: @James Have a look at `listings` or `minted`, both can automatically wrap lines