# Lyx / Knitr - R Code in chunck goes beyond set width

Tags: formatting, lyx, r, width, knitr

I use Lyx (2.1.4) with knitr (1.10.5). I have a lot of trouble having the code chunks respect the width that I tried setting through various ways:

1. In the chunk options (`width=50`);
2. `options("width")=50` at the top of my document
3. `opts_chunk$set(width=50)` also at the top of my document

The results are always the same:

[image]

What am I missing? Any help appreciated.

**Edit:** I realized that it has to do with the quoted string which won't be broken into several lines. Without long strings, the width setting is respected. (Still, the problem remains unsolved.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If your edit to your question answers your question, you should consider providing an actual answer, rather than just editing your question.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question, just points out more precisely where the problem is... I added a small sentence at the end to make that clear.

Comment: If you don't consider it an answer, you might wish to provide a minimal working example (MWE) for folks to play with. (See [LyX user questions on TeX stackexchange](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4488/32888).) However, I'd also point out that this is ultimately a problem for R, not TeX/LyX, at least the way that you want to do it. See [How to wrap text in R source with tidy and knitr](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14901781/2571049) on Stack Overflow. There are some hacky solutions there. If you don't want a hacky solution, use `listings` or `minted`.

Comment: You can [use `listings` with `knitr`](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/listings/), but I'm not super familiar with how this works.

Comment: There's actually a good answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41552/32888) that shows how to use the `breaklines` option of `listings` with `knitr`. Does this help?

Comment: This is promising. Will test it and report the results later on. Thank you Adam.

Comment: Sorry for the off-topic comment, but "alternative intéressant" should be "alternative intéressante" right?

Comment: Haha yes, thank you for noticing this. Feminine it is indeed. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ok so thanks to Adam's help, I was able to see there actually *is* a workaround for this. However, it involves a fair bit of tweaking in order to make the chunks appear the same way as my other chunks do. So for now, my solution was to set `tidy=FALSE` and `eval=FALSE` in the chunk options, and put this in the chunk:

```
boxplot(fumeurs$imc, horizontal=TRUE, main="Distribution de 
+    l'indice de masse corporelle", xlab="IMC (Kg/m^2)")
```

That way, the chunk appears exactly as would another one (that is, without spilling over the margins). Then, in another chunk just after (or just before) this one, I create another one having `echo=FALSE` as an option, and put into it the R code as it is intended (with the long string unbroken). Kinda dirty, but it seems that it is the best fix that doesn't require a full day of tweaking around.

See the links in Adam's comments to my question if you are willing to go through the `listings + hook` route, and best of luck to you!