# Verbatim Linebreaks

Tags: line-breaking, verbatim

I would like to enable automatic line breaking in `Verbatim` environment; besides I do not want to use `lstlisting` as it will not have exactly the same font shapes as `Verbatim` and some other special characters used in Logic Programming like `\+` does not show the same. I should only use `Verbatim` environment but it seems that the option of line breaking is not available. `fancyvrb` also doesn't work as we need to know when we want the line to break. I need this to be automatic.

Comment: Please take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11973/verbatim-environment-and-line-breaking?rq=1

Comment: @Papiro: The solution in the linked question uses [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) which the OP wants to avoid. Not sure why...

Answer (score 3):

Here a small hack. It saves the contents of a verbatim line inside a vertical box which allows line breaks:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\box_new:N \l_fvrb_box
\tl_new:N \l_fvrb_tl

\RenewDocumentCommand \FancyVerbFormatLine { m }
 {
   \hbox_set:Nn \l_fvrb_box { #1 }
    \dim_compare:nNnTF { \box_wd:N \l_fvrb_box }>{ \linewidth }
      {%box to big 
       \fvrb_use_linecontents:n { #1 }
      } 
      {%box fits
       \box_use:N \l_fvrb_box
      }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \fvrb_use_linecontents:n  #1
 {
  \group_begin:
   \vbox_set:Nn \l_fvrb_box
     {\hsize=\linewidth\parindent0pt
       \advance\hsize by -2em
       \hspace*{-2em}
        #1
     }
    \hspace*{2em}\box_use:N \l_fvrb_box
  \group_end:
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}
asdsadsadsa asd  a

asdsadsadsa asd  asd  asd sa sd sd as  sdadas sa+ dsa +sa++94+4+ +4sd+as 
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```